# jQuery UI Selectable Not Working With .dialog open html

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, selectable

I am opening a .dialog modal and loading html.  I am applying jQuery selectable to a list that is in the html and displayed in the .dialog modal.  Selectable is not working, the straight html for the list is being displayed.

Code:

```
  $jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       ...
       dayClick:

       ...


         var $test_dialog = jQuery('<div></div>').html('<ul id="selectable">
           <li>1</li>
           <li>2</li>
           <li>3</li>
        </ul>').dialog(//buttons);

    }) // end fullCalendar

    $test_dialog.dialog('open')

    jQuery('#selectable').selectable();
```

Other details:

I am loading fullCalendar on a page, and when the user clicks on the calendar, the .dialog modal with the list opens.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: are you sure you applying selectable function after the html is fully loaded?

Comment: where is your selectable() being called? It's not in the code you pasted

Comment: forgot to add that line, the selectable() call is after the .dialog open, I added it in the sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always make sure you've loaded the html first before actually calling the selectable function.

```
$(function() {
  var html = '';
  html += '<ul id="selectable">';
  html += '<li>1</li>';
  html += '<li>2</li>';
  html += '<li>3</li>';
  html += '</ul>';
  $('#dialog').html(html).dialog();
  $('#selectable').selectable();
});
```

here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/N4spA/)

Comment: Ok, figured it out.  Themeroller did not create chrome for the selectable classes.  Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar sounding issue but a different solution.  For me, the issue was recognizing that I need to add the class `ui-widget-content` to the individual elements that were to be considered selectable.  By contrast, I could just call `.draggable()` on them and they became draggable without adding any classes.